# Facebook Share using angularJS and html5mode(true)

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, angularjs, pushstate

I'm developing an angularJS app using html5Mode(true).

In the header of my main index file I added

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

so whenever google crawls any of my pages it will add **"?_extracted_fragment_="** to the end of the url:

```
 http://example.com/path/to/nowhere?_extracted_fragment_=
```

This way I know when to serve the angular app and when to serve static content.

Facebook however seems to ignore this meta tag and only adds **"?_extracted_fragment_="** if it finds a hashbang **"#!"** in the URL. So sharing doesn't work

Is there any other way to tell the Facebook crawler to look up the static content, without using hashbangs or having to detect the Facebook crawler?

Comment: If you control what address is used to share, see to it that it the “right” address in the first place by specifying it explicitly. If you don’t – then you will have to recognize the scraper to redirect it to the correct address.

Comment: That's what I didn't want to do as it would break whenever a user shares the URL from the browser window. I updated my htaccess to detect the facebook crawler user agent and it works like this. (But I'm still hoping there's another way to do this)